# CSS não aplica 100%

Tags: html, css, height

Boa noite, estou utilizando CSS para estilização de um menu na vertical, porém quando tento aplicar 100% de altura ele não corresponde

código html

```
<div class="menu-principal">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">            
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
li:first-child {
    height: 150px;
    background:black;
    text-align: center
}

li a:hover {
    background:black;
}

a {
    color: white;
}

.menu-principal {
    height: 100%;
    width: 240px;
    background: red;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o menu em vermelho deveria pegar 100% da altura

obs: estou utilizando bootstrap tb

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa também dizer, pra `body` e `html` que eles precisam de 100% de `height`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Não funciona, brother